# Can VSCodeVim Ignore Windows Key Combination?

Tags: vim, vscodevim

I have Windows+I set as a keyboard shortcut to open up chrome, but if I try to use that while keyboard focus is on VSCode with vscodevim enabled, it treats it as if I had just typed I by itself (and enters insert mode).

I'm running mate desktop manager on Arch Linux. The Win-I shortcut is set through system -> preferences -> hardware -> keyboard shortcuts.

I've tried adding the following to settings.json:

```
    "vim.handleKeys": {
        "<T-i>": false
    }
```

I've also tried `<Win-i>`, `<T-I>`, `<Win-I>`, `<Mod4-I>`.

Is there a different syntax to specifiy windows key being pressed? Or a different way to have ideavim register that it's pressed and ignore the input? The key is displayed as Mod4 in the mate keyboard shortcuts menu.

I know I can map the chrome shortcut to something else like Alt+F3, but I'm hoping to keep it as Win+I if possible. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following setting:

```
"keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode"
```

Restart vscode after that.

Comment: No luck when including that and all the handlekeys flags from OP in my settings.json :(